# Prevent Download Files in Document Library

Tags: 2013, pdf

I want that users can't download the pdf files. Only read them but when I select an file it opens in Adobe and ask "Checkout& Open " or "Open".

When I select "Open" I can't download but when I select "Checkout & Open" it asks my username. I can cancel the question and just move on. Then It reopen the file and I can save/download it.

How can it happen? It shouldn't make me download or save it. How can I disable this with Sharepoint and the Adobe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the pdf security as cannot be downloaded and then embed it in the website. So when user wants to open pdf he/she has to read it from the website.

Comment: how did you embeded into sharepoint site , without ability to download the pdf?